# Выбор в производительности PHP 7.4 native vs Phalcon 4

Tags: php, производительность, phalcon, php7.4

Планирую написать высокопроизводительное веб-приложение, что-то вроде API. Важным пунктом является производительность.
Приложение будет содержать базовые набор 
"Модель-контроллер" с возможностями:

- добавление;
- редактирования;
- удаление;
- получение информации(с возможностью фильтрования).

В качестве СУБД используется MySQL.

Прочитал, что phalcon использует C-шные функции, по этой причине он производительнее native. Я решил сам проверить, написав простое приложение на phalcon'e и на native. И на мое мнение native немного выигрывает.

Стоит ли использовать phalcon для такого приложения?
В каких случая он может дать прирост, возможно я не правильного его использую?

Comment: нативный пхп (не таская с собой фреймворки) работающий с опкешем тоже по сути своей будет использовать сишные функции для доступа к БД, например. для фалкона на Си также написаны и ОРМ и шаблонизаторы и т.п. Главное, чтобы вы не написали на нем приложение, и не решили потом поставить его на хостинг за 100рублей/месяц, куда вы не в состоянии будете установить эти самые модули. Насколько большие нагрузки вы ожидаете, чтобы хотите выбрать такой инструмент?

Comment: @ teran, хостинг vps выше средней категории. Нагрузка не стабильная, планируется около 1 000 000+  подключений в день. И хотелось максимально выжать с сервера.